How to create a loop that subsamples dataset, runs a specific equation, and gives you a list of p-values for each sub-samples?
There is a previous question which asks a similar question (Is there a way to create a loop where I provide a function and dataframe and subsample it, and repeat the function with a subsample N times?), but the solution there appears to provide an answer as to how to get the p value of a simple the correlation between two parts of a dataset, rather than how to subsample and get p-values for a specific function, as I describe above?
Specifically, I have a function which looks like this:
AvianGEE <- compar.gee(Dichromatism ~Temp*Precip, data = BirdData, phy = TrimAvianTree)

The output of this provides the headings:
Estimate         S.E.       t      Pr(T > |t|)

I want to be able subsample a random 100 species of bird, 999 times, and get a list of the
Pr(T > |t|) values of each run of the Generalised Estimating Equation.
compar.gee is a function of the ape package, and produces an object of the "compar.gee" class
Here is an example of the data which I am using for this analysis. Firstly the data on birds:
BirdData <- structure(
    list(
      Species = c(
        "Acanthagenys_rufogularis",
        "Acanthiza_apicalis",
        "Acanthiza_chrysorrhoa",
        "Acanthiza_lineata",
        "Acanthiza_nana",
        "Acanthiza_uropygialis"
      ),
      Temp = c(27.1, 27.63,
               28.8, 32.16, 29.95, 28.24),
      Precip = c(630,
                 475, 765, 900, 780, 590),
      Dichromatism = c(0.45,
                       0.3, 0.55, 0.69, 0.24, 0.58),
      row.names = c(
        "Acanthagenys_rufogularis",
        "Acanthiza_apicalis",
        "Acanthiza_chrysorrhoa",
        "Acanthiza_lineata",
        "Acanthiza_nana",
        "Acanthiza_uropygialis"
      )
    )) |> as.data.frame()

And here is the phylogeny, cut down to try to be able to fit the information in here:
TrimAvianTree <- list(edge = structure(c(597L, 598L, 599L, 600L, 601L), dim = c(866L, 2L
)), tip.label = c("Chiroxiphia_linearis", "Chiroxiphia_pareola", 
                  "Chiroxiphia_caudata", "Manacus_manacus", "Pipra_erythrocephala"))

# Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : 
# dims [product 1732] do not match the length of object [5]

I tried the very promising solution offered below, and got the following error:
library(ape)
library(gee)
compar.gee(Dichromatism ~ Temp*Precip, data = BirdData, phy = TrimAvianTree)

# Error: object 'TrimAvianTree' not found

> replicate(n = 999, {res <- compar.gee(Dichromatism ~ Temp*Precip,
+                                       data = sample_N(BirdData, 100), 
+                                       phy = TrimAvianTree
+ )
+ coef_summary(res)[, "Pr(T > |t|)"]                 
+ }
+ )
Error in d:nrow(100) : argument of length 0
Called from: sample(d:nrow(100), N)
Browse[1]> c

traceback to this error gave me this:
Error in d:nrow(100) : argument of length 0
9.
sample(d:nrow(100), N)
8.
`[.data.frame`(d, sample(d:nrow(100), N), )
7.
d[sample(d:nrow(100), N), ]
6.
sample_N(BirdData, 100)
5.
compar.gee(Dichromatism ~ Temp * Precip, data = sample_N(BirdData, 
100), phy = TrimAvianTree)
4.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
3.
lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
2.
sapply(integer(n), eval.parent(substitute(function(...) expr)), 
simplify = simplify)
1.
replicate(n = 999, {
res <- compar.gee(Dichromatism ~ Temp * Precip, 
data = sample_N(BirdData, 100), phy = TrimAvianTree)
coef_summary(res)[, "Pr(T > |t|)"] ...

The expected output would be something along the lines of a list of p values for the effect of Temp, Precip, and Temp*Precip, on dichromatism. I do not know the exact format that would be, but something like this:
Temp     Precip    Temp*Precip
0.03     0.52      0.33          
0.07     0.66      0.28
0.009    0.57      0.34

I have managed to do some advances on this, but basically the issue at the moment is how to have a loop within the repeated compare.gee. Is there some way to adjust the
replicate(n = 999, {res <- compar.gee(Dichromatism ~Temp*Precip,
                                    data = sample_N(BirdData, 100), 
                                    phy = TrimAvianTree
                                    )
                  coef_summary(res)[, "Pr(T > |t|)"]                 
                  }
)

So that every time the sample_N(BirdData, 100)function gets a new list of 100 birds, I can trim the phylogeny doing keep.tip(TrimAvianTree, RandomSubset$Species), with RandomSubset being each random subset of 100 species?
I have tried the following:
replicate(n = 999, {randomdf <- sample_N(BirdData,100)}
{res <- compar.gee(Dichromatism ~Temp*Precip,
                                            data = sample_N(BirdData, 100), 
                                            phy = keep.tip(TrimAvianTree, randomdf$Species)
                                            )
                          coef_summary(res)[, "Pr(T > |t|)"]                 
                          }
        )

So that the random sampling would be replicated 999 times, and each time the phylogeny would be altered to only include relevant species. However, I got the following error:
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"PValues <- replicate(n = 999, {randomdf <- sample_N(BirdData,100)} 
                     {"

When I tried running it without {}, and instead using randomdf <- sample_N(BirdData,100), or (randomdf <- sample_N(BirdData,100)) to distinguish between the two functions being repeated, I got this error:
Error in higher && length(c.dim <- unique(lapply(x, dim))) == 1 : 
  'length = 4' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
>

I have been asked how I made my phylogeny, so this is how I did it. To create a phylogeny, first you download family backbones from BirdTree (https://birdtree.org/downloads/)
You can then read them using the read.tree function from the ape package
Overall_Trees <- read.tree("mnt/data/projects/birdphylo/Tree_sets/Stage2_full_data/CombinedTrees/AllBirdsHackett1.tre")

You then make a consensus tree:
Overall_Tree_Consensus <- consensus(Overall_Trees, p = 1, 
                                    check.labels = T, rooted = T)

Followed by cutting it to only include species in your dataset:
TrimAvianTree <- keep.tip(Overall_Tree_Consensus, BirdData $Species)

For the compare.gee function, you have to provide branch lengths. I do so as follows:
TrimAvianTree <- compute.brlen(TrimAvianTree, method = "Grafen", power = 1)

Then just make sure that the species names match up between your phylogeny and your dataset, as follows:
name.check(TrimAvianTree, BirdData)

A key thing to note here is that the row names are the species names, and there is a column called "Species"

Sounds like you want to bootstrap a statistic with R?

The problem which I have is that the answer in the question which I linked to seems to provided a way to get a simple correlation p value or a linear model (the cor.test() function calculating the Pearson correlation coefficient as default) which would not be appropriate for my data or the analysis I wish to do. I want to have the p values of the phylogenetic generalised estimating equation, as shown above, when I re-run the analysis 999 times, each time with 100 random species. That might be a form of bootstrapping, but I thought bootstrapping didnt involve subsampling

What data would be most useful to include in my question to help you answer it?

I have added an example of the data I have, the expected output would be a list of p values of the effect of Temp, Precip, and Temp*Precip on Dichromatism if I re-run the analysis 999 times with 100 random species

I have added what I think the output could look like, I hope that this makes it clearer. Thank you again

I think that the error is due to. the phylogenies of the random subset not matching the global phylogeny of species included. Do you know how to integrate the drop.tip function into a loop so that each time a random subset is created a phylogeny only including that subset is included for the compare.gee function?

@Birdman sorry for asking again and again, but I cannot find that compar.gee function.  Can you include a code that you did one time so that the result is first line of the expected output.  Do not forget to include all external packages.

@Birdman, see the revised/edited question and check.  The errors I am getting are included there

I think the issue with the errors you’ve got is that I haven’t included all of my data in the question (there’s just too much of it for it to be practicable), so I’ve just used the dput function to give the top 5 rows of my data. The compare.gee function is in the ape package

@Birdman, but I am unable to create TrimAvianTree that's why I requested you to include code where you calculated/tried to calculate output

What output? If you want I can show you how to create a phylogeny and trim it down to only a few species

Yes @Birdman, I need that

@AnilGoyal I have added an explanation on how I made the phylogeny and trimmed it

There's a couple of steps involved:

randomly subsetting your data
running compar.gee and extracting the desired information from the result
repeating above

1 There's various ways to randomly subset a dataframe, e. g. sample_n from {dplyr}. Let's roll a poor man's version with base R like so:
sample_N <- \(d, N) d[sample(1:nrow(d), N),]

2 While coef is the function of choice to extract a model's coefficients, compar.gee prints some extra info as a side effect but does not return this as part of the result. By inspecting ape:::print.compar.gee, we can pull the corresponding calculations into a custom function which returns rather than prints the extra info:
coef_summary <- function (x){ ## x being your `compar.gee` output
    nas <- is.na(x$coef)
    coef <- x$coef[!nas]
    cnames <- names(coef)
    coef <- matrix(rep(coef, 4), ncol = 4)
    dimnames(coef) <- list(cnames, c("Estimate", "S.E.", "t", "Pr(T > |t|)"))
    df <- x$dfP - dim(coef)[1]
    coef[, 2] <- sqrt(diag(x$W))
    coef[, 3] <- coef[, 1]/coef[, 2]
    if (df < 0) {
        warning("not enough degrees of freedom to compute P-values.")
        coef[, 4] <- NA
    }
    else coef[, 4] <- 2 * (1 - pt(abs(coef[, 3]), df))
    coef
}

... now you can extract the desired coefficient descriptor like, e. g.:
coef_summary(your_compar.gee_here)[, "Pr(T > |t|)"]

3 we can now use, e. g. replicate to obtain a bootstrapped estimate:
replicate(n = 999, {res <- compar.gee(Dichromatism ~Temp*Precip,
                                    data = sample_N(BirdData, 100), 
                                    phy = TrimAvianTree
                                    )
                  coef_summary(res)[, "Pr(T > |t|)"]                 
                  }
)

Note that above is a dry run, for lack of example data. Reshaping the output of the replicated code might be necessary.

Thanks. I tried this method and get the following error at the last step:Error in d:nrow(100) : argument of length 0
I will add an example of my data so you can see where I may have gone wrong

I will add the error I get when running the debugger as well

For a reproducible example, you also need to supply TrimAvianTree; note that the structure you supplied for BirdData is not a data.frame. Maybe converting it with as.data.frame solves the issue anyway.

I tried converting to data.frame using as.data.frame and got the same error. I will add more information now. Thanks again.

Okay I think I figured out the issue. the compare.gee function only works when you have a phylogeny which exactly matches the species list in the data frame, which is not the case for the random subset. How would one add the drop.tip() function for each random subset to the phylogeny to make a new phylogeny each iteration, that exactly matches the species included in the random subset?

I have added my attempts to find a solution to this issue, and the error responses I got
